# Uncrypting a very simple code in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode, lowercase

So this is the brief:
i need to input something like:

```
BaSe fOO ThE AttAcK
```

and return:

```
attack the base.
```

As you can see to decode this i need to start by reading the words in reverse order and if the first letter of the word isupper() then make it lowercase and append it to a list which i will later print. This is what i have so far:

```
# Enter your code for "BaSe fOO ThE AttAcK" here.
default = input('code: ')
listdefault = default.split()
uncrypted = []
for i in range(len(listdefault)):
  if listdefault[:-i].istitle(): # doesn't work
    i = i.lower() # dont know if this works, Should convert word to lower case.
    uncrypted.append(i)
solution = ' '.join(uncrypted)
print(solution)
```

Can someone show me how to get this program to work? Says that i can't use the istitle() method on a list type..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but you're switching between treating `i` as an index (`for i in range...`) and as the word itself (`uncrypted.append(i)`). And you probably meant `listdefault[i].istitle()` rather than `listdefault[:-i].istitle()`.

The best solution is to change it to:

```
for w in listdefault[::-1]:
    if w.istitle():
        w = w.lower()
        uncrypted.append(w)
```

Since `listdefault[::-1]` is a way to reverse the list (`reversed(listdefault)` also works). If you know how to use list comprehensions, you can do it in one line:

```
solution = ' '.join([w.lower() for w in listdefault[::-1] if w.istitle()])
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done much simpler...

```
text = input("Code: ")
result = [w.lower() for w in reversed(text.split()) if w[0].isupper()]
print(' '.join(result))
```

```
Code: BaSe fOO ThE AttAcK
attack the base
```

I hope this makes you want to learn Python deeper.

By the way, you can't use `.istitle()` for this task, because it checks whether *only* the first letter is uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

This is a plausible solution:

```
default = input('code: ')
listdefault = default.split()
uncrypted = []
for i in reversed(listdefault):
    if i[0].isupper():
        i = i.lower()
        uncrypted.append(i)
solution = ' '.join(uncrypted)
print('says:',solution)
```